# Error conectar Firebase a app Android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

estoy intentando implementar Firebase en mi app android pero no consigo que funcione. Os cuento los pasos que he seguido

1. Me he registrado en firebase
2. He creado un proyecto en firebase
3. En la carpeta app de mi aplicacion he
       añadido el fichero google-services.json
4. He añadido en los gradle las siguientes lineas:

> build.grade

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services plugin
```

> app/build.grade

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
}
//Esta linea esta fuera de las dependencies
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Una vez hecho esto he realizado un sync now y no me ha dado ningun problema. Pero a la hora de realizar un registro me da error y me dice que no se ha podido registrar al usuario y no se como hacer porque ya he probado haciendolo asi y siguiendo los pasos del firebase desde el propio android studio pero las lineas que me añade el asistente ese al gradle no compilan.
Os dejo por aqui el codigo de la clase .java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

//defining view objects
private EditText TextEmail;
private EditText TextPassword;
private Button btnRegistrar;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


//Declaramos un objeto firebaseAuth
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //inicializamos el objeto firebaseAuth
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //Referenciamos los views
    TextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtEmail);
    TextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtPassword);

    btnRegistrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonRegistrar);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    //attaching listener to button
    btnRegistrar.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void registrarUsuario(){

    //Obtenemos el email y la contraseña desde las cajas de texto
    String email = TextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password  = TextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    //Verificamos que las cajas de texto no esten vacías
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Se debe ingresar un email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Falta ingresar la contraseña",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }


    progressDialog.setMessage("Realizando registro en linea...");
    progressDialog.show();

    //creating a new user
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    //checking if success
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Se ha registrado el usuario con el email: "+ TextEmail.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No se pudo registrar el usuario ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //Invocamos al método:
    registrarUsuario();
}
```

Os añado tambien los archivos del gradle por si la he liado ahi a la hora de introducir los servicios pero no se porque he seguido los pasos que vienen en la documentacion de goolge.

**build.grade**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app/build.grade**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.josemanuu.intento2"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda :)

Comment: Habilitante el registro de usuario y contraseña en la consola de firebase ?

Comment: Si, en firebase esta todo configurado para que los usuarios se registren usando correo y password

Comment: Si no compilan como dices, debe dar algún error, ¿cuál es ese error?

Comment: Lo que tengo ahí puesto si compila pero a la hora de registrar a un usuario me da el error del else de task.isSuccesful

Comment: que error te da ?

Comment: Si añado el codigo que me da el asistente de AndroidStudio me dice -> Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta hacer en el else esto: task.getException() para indicarnos cuál es el error y a su vez task.getException().getMessage(). Con eso intentaré ayudarte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, gracias a eso he conseguido solucionarloo. Resulta que por defecto google me pide una password de al menos 6 caracteres y la mia no los tenia por eso me daba error todo el rato y no por que no pudiera conectarme a firebase. Gracias por decirme lo del getException().getMessage() sin eso no lo habria visto jajajajajaj

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido! Puedes poner en el else lo siguiente: try { throw task.getException(); } catch (Exception e) { //manejar los errores al registrar un nuevo usuario } //en vez de usar solo Exception puedes fijarte las distintas excepciones de Auth que tiene firebase y capturar cada una en un catch particular (por ejemplo si el correo electrónico ya está registrado lanzará otra excepción) Saludos!